The Patrol test is not showing test results
How do I see the results of my patrol tests in VS code when running the patrol cli with this command?

patrol test -t integration_test/mng_vgn_itm/add_to_location_test.dart
--flavor development --dart-define-from-file lib/config/environment_strings_dev.json

I just see:

I noticed there are HTML files with the results in:

build/app/reports/androidTests/connected/debug/flavors/development

That I can open in Chrome. Isn't there a terminal result log? It's quite inconvenient to find that file and open it in Chrome every time.

Let's try to run on develop mode and add more verbose information like:
patrol develop test -t integration_test/test_file.dart --verbose

